# Crystal reports: Login failed for user '....'

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a **desktop application** developed with **visual studio 2010, crystal reports, and dot net version 4**. The application was installed on the server with sqlserver 2008 as database and was shared over a **domain network**. On the client side the crystal report shows the **login information**(SQL authentication) to the server. Once the information is provided it works for two to three times and then shows **"login failed for user ...."**. I went to the services panel on the server and **restarted the MSSQL service**. The problem resolved but again after two attempts it shows the same error message. Is there a way to resolve this problem instead of keeping on restarting the MSSQL service

SQL server 2008 R2
Dot net v4
MS VS 2010

Comment: any chance its sql express?

Comment: Na its SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: its unusual for sql to go wobbly that quick. Check max connections etc? no memory constraints stuff like that going on?